# No metrics returned for AllSubscribers List

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud

Currently we're trying to pull data from All Subscribers List.
If we do not set any filter, the List isn't returned at all.

If we give it a hard filter on the ID, we do not get any data:

```
  <par:RetrieveRequest>
    <par:ObjectType>List</par:ObjectType>
    <par:Properties>ID</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ListName</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ModifiedDate</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>Type</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ListClassification</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>Description</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>Category</par:Properties>
    <par:Filter xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
     <par:Property>ID</par:Property>
     <par:SimpleOperator>equals</par:SimpleOperator>
     <par:Value>23482</par:Value>
    </par:Filter>
   </par:RetrieveRequest>
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
   <RequestID>4351fe1e-de84-460e-b5a4-8c5393f850d2</RequestID>
  </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

Similarly, if we filter it by name:

```
  <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
   <RequestID>98d17a1d-7123-4245-836e-55ddf75efaea</RequestID>
   <Results xsi:type="List">
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
    <ModifiedDate>2013-12-27T18:48:54.24</ModifiedDate>
    <ID>24319</ID>
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
    <ListName>All Subscribers</ListName>
    <Category>110443</Category>
    <Type>Private</Type>
    <Description>Contains all subscribers</Description>
    <ListClassification>ExactTargetList</ListClassification>
   </Results>
  </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

Is there a setting we need to configure so we can retrieve the All Subscribers List via the SOAP API?

Comment: <par:RetrieveRequest>
    <par:ObjectType>List</par:ObjectType>
    <par:Properties>ID</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ListName</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ModifiedDate</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>Type</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>ListClassification</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>Description</par:Properties>
    <par:Properties>Category</par:Properties>
    <par:Filter xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
     <par:Property>ID</par:Property>
     <par:SimpleOperator>equals</par:SimpleOperator>
     <par:Value>23482</par:Value>
    </par:Filter>

Comment: Nadia, you can edit your question to update it with additional information. Can you try doing so with what you've commented ?

Comment: Yes,  please edit the question according to above instructions.  Also,  what data are you expecting to see?

Comment: @Nadia Have you been able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion on what you are actually retrieving here.  You are asking the API for the list object, and are indeed getting it. However, it seems as though you want the subscribers from that list.

First, the object type should be [`ListSubscriber`](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsubscriber/).

The filter you are using should be something like this:

```
<par:Property>List.ID</par:Property>
<par:SimpleOperator>equals</par:SimpleOperator>
<par:Value>23482</par:Value>
```

Your properties to be returned should also include the details about the subscriber you wish to retrieve as well. I would suggest excluding parameters initially and return all information, then add in only what you need.